# How to derive and understand the covariance property of the curvature bivector in Gauge Theory Gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature, clifford-algebra

In David Hestenes' [Gauge Theory Gravity paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10701-005-5828-y) ([RG](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226117395_Gauge_Theory_Gravity_with_Geometric_Calculus)), the curvature tensor is defined via

$$ [D_\mu, D_\nu] M = R(g_\mu \wedge g_\nu) \times M $$

therefore

$$ R(g_\mu \wedge g_\nu) = D_\mu \omega_\nu - D_\nu \omega_\mu - \omega_\mu \times \omega_\nu. $$

While it is fairly straightforward to compute the expression for $R$ given the LHS with the commutator, the idea that $R$ is some (linear?) function of a set of basis bivectors is a little abstract. It becomes more urgent to understand this dependence on $g_\mu \wedge g_\nu$ because the covariance property is derived to be

$$ \bar{L}: R(g_\mu \wedge g_\nu) \quad \rightarrow \quad R^\prime(g_\mu^\prime \wedge g^\prime_\nu) = \bar{L} R(\underline{L}(g_\mu \wedge g_\nu)) $$

where $\underline{L} \equiv \bar{L}^{-1}$, and $\bar{L}A \equiv L A \tilde{L}$ for any multivector $A$.

I'm not able to derive this covariance property because I don't understand what is meant by $\underline{L}(g_\mu \wedge g_\nu) = \tilde{L}(g_\mu \wedge g_\nu)L$, since this bivector argument is too abstract. For example, to even begin a proof, what is the expression for $R(\underline{L}(g_\mu \wedge g_\nu))$?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4185929/568204) for some intuition/elaboration on why the curvature of a connection on a vector bundle $(E,\pi,M)$ is an $\text{End}(E)$-valued 2-form on $M$. The $2$-from nature means it is (at each point) a linear map from bivectors to endomorphisms, $\bigwedge^2(T_pM)\to \text{End}(E_p)$.